# Adobe Air - Detect javascript events

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, dom, air

Is there a way for air to listen to dom mutation events, such as onsubtreemodified or onnodeinserted?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use ExternalInterface.addCallback("exposedFunctionName", closure); to expose callback functions on the SWF that a JS event-listening script could call.